# Why isn't custom.ini being used by Grafana for APT version on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, grafana

I first tried installing Grafana on Windows and was able to use custom.ini just fine to override `[auth.anonymous]` in the defaults.ini configuration file.

However when performing the same thing with the Linux APT version on Ubuntu 20.04 I’m having zero luck.

Grafana just steadfastly refuses to read my custom.ini file.

What’s going on here?

The APT version should use the custom.ini file as far as I can make out from the Grafana documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. APT versions also use grafana.ini